# How to use caching on CosmosDB queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmosDB Database and querying it all the time is pointless, I need to implement caching because the RUs are sky high. I am using the data from an MVC Application. Using conventional OutputCache on the controllers is not an option. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked into [Azure Redis Cache](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cache/)?

Comment: Or a simple MemoryCache. It all depends on sizes, available key candidates, ...

Comment: There are many potential caching solutions; what you use is really up to you, and doesn't really apply specifically to Cosmos DB. As for the "sky high" RU cost (and knowing what that means): there's really know way to understand your RU cost without seeing your data shape, queries, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have queried your data, cosmosDB is no longer relevant and you can use your favorite caching toolset for caching the POCOs. Any you like.

You could start with simple BCL caching tools: [System.Runtime.Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.110).aspx). `MemoryCache` class skips serialization overhead and it's really simple to get started. Some friendlier intro is also here: http://deanhume.com/object-caching-net-4/

If you really need a distributed cache and the overhead to your infra complexity and management is acceptable, then a good candidate could be Redis. You could also switch to Redis later as a caching provider under System.Runtime.Caching, should you choose to keep using the System.Runtime.Caching API. See [some nuget package seemingly relevant](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=RedisObjectCache).

#### Warning

Obviously you should cache only data which is allowed to be stale. Not everything can be cached. You should definitely recheck your CosmosDB data model and indexes as RU costs of a well-designed system should never be interpreted as "sky-high", maybe just up to "actively used" ;)